# What is the probability to have -1 points at the end?

Tags: probability

> 8 white ball, 4 black balls, and 2 red balls (The total is 12 balls). We draw 2 balls without replacement (Without returning back). A white ball cost one point. A black ball adds 2 points and a red ball cost zero points.
>   The player start with zero points.
>
> 1. What is the probability to have -1 points at the end?

My answers which are incorrect:

1. To get -1 points, we need to draw a white ball and then a red ball or the opposite. In each case, we choose one ball from the total in that color.

$$ \frac{\binom{8}{1}\binom{2}{1}+\binom{2}{1}\binom{8}{1}}{\binom{14}{2}} $$

The correct answer is:
$$ \frac{\binom{8}{1}\binom{2}{1}}{\binom{14}{2}} $$

I don't understand why.

Comment: Because the ${8 \choose 1}$ applies to *either* the first or the second draw, and the ${2 \choose 1}$ applies to the "other" draw.

Comment: How did you conclude that?

Comment: I concluded that by the fact that your ${14 \choose 2}$ involved *either* order.  Either keep order relevant in BOTH numerator and denominator, or *irrelevant* in BOTH numerator and denominator.  Don't mix them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer lies in the fact that your numerator is in terms of ordered couples, while your denominator in terms of unordered couples.

If you want to keep the same numerator, the denominator should be the number of arrangements of two among $14$, that is twice the value it is now.